# Correlating a resampled data array with a constant array in python

Tags: python-3.x, python-xarray

I am trying to use a bootstrap resampling technique to test the significance of the correlation between rainfall data and an index. I would like the rainfall data to be resampled/shuffled 1000 times, but the index data to remain the same. Then each of the shuffled rainfall datasets must be correlated with the constant index dataset (generating 1000 random correlations over the lat-lon region). I have the following code:

```
# Number of bootstrap samples
num_bootstrap_samples = 1000

# Function to calculate spearman correlation
def calculate_correlation(data1, data2):
    return xs.spearman_r(data1, data2, dim='time')

# Calculate the observed correlation
observed_correlation = calculate_correlation(cru_djf_uv, nino_djf)

# Initialize an array to store bootstrap samples
bootstrap_correlations = np.zeros((num_bootstrap_samples, cru_djf_uv.shape[1], cru_djf_uv.shape[2]))

# Perform bootstrap resampling
for i in range(num_bootstrap_samples):
    # Resample with replacement
    resampled_indices = np.random.choice(cru_djf_uv.shape[0], cru_djf_uv.shape[0], replace=True)
    resampled_cru = cru_djf_uv.isel(time=resampled_indices)
    
    # Calculate correlation for the resampled data
    bootstrap_correlations[i, :, :] = calculate_correlation(resampled_cru, nino_djf)
```

However, when I run this I get an error (ValueError: indexes along dimension 'time' are not equal). I think it is because the years no longer match up in the two series (which is what I want) but how do I fix the error?
Here is what the precipitation dataset looks like (cru_djf_uv):

```
<xarray.DataArray 'pre' (time: 30, lat: 18, lon: 6)>
array([[[243.      , 294.80002 , 309.40002 , 308.5     , 358.4     ,
         414.7     ],
        [240.1     , 254.      , 305.3     , 328.7     , 392.90002 ,
         401.9     ],
        [224.70001 , 271.7     , 282.1     , 393.4     , 487.9     ,
         478.5     ],
        ...,
        [181.09999 , 206.30002 , 234.20001 , 245.5     , 223.1     ,
         278.9     ],
        [176.8     , 207.      , 213.3     , 208.1     , 196.2     ,
         229.30002 ],
        [195.6     , 216.      , 211.7     , 186.6     , 172.4     ,
         165.3     ]],

       [[322.80002 , 370.9     , 427.7     , 393.7     , 389.09998 ,
         425.5     ],
        [274.9     , 292.7     , 425.8     , 398.80002 , 437.2     ,
         361.80002 ],
        [229.5     , 281.6     , 368.9     , 455.6     , 577.8     ,
         380.7     ],
...
        [223.      , 221.40001 , 237.4     , 238.20001 , 241.9     ,
         290.1     ],
        [236.2     , 237.4     , 232.5     , 215.      , 216.5     ,
         252.8     ],
        [253.6     , 261.19998 , 239.40001 , 203.1     , 191.7     ,
         201.5     ]],

       [[304.8     , 360.2     , 365.90002 , 338.80002 , 360.40002 ,
         412.90002 ],
        [326.6     , 343.1     , 366.      , 358.4     , 398.6     ,
         361.90002 ],
        [313.80002 , 359.9     , 349.3     , 410.5     , 494.4     ,
         404.      ],
        ...,
        [273.3     , 260.2     , 264.3     , 261.2     , 263.9     ,
         315.2     ],
        [258.1     , 251.6     , 240.20001 , 221.1     , 222.4     ,
         256.6     ],
        [259.30002 , 266.30002 , 241.5     , 201.40001 , 188.90001 ,
         197.5     ]]], dtype=float32)
Coordinates:
  * time     (time) datetime64[ns] 1984-12-01 1985-12-01 ... 2013-12-01
  * lon      (lon) float32 27.25 27.75 28.25 28.75 29.25 29.75
  * lat      (lat) float32 -30.75 -30.25 -29.75 -29.25 ... -23.25 -22.75 -22.25
```

Here is what the index dataset looks like (nino_djf):

```
<xarray.DataArray 'ANOM' (time: 30)>
array([-0.94333333, -0.45333333,  1.26333333,  0.84333333, -1.66666667,
        0.16333333,  0.52      ,  1.90333333,  0.26666667,  0.24      ,
        1.14      , -0.75333333, -0.38333333,  2.37      , -1.43      ,
       -1.54666667, -0.62666667, -0.06666667,  1.00666667,  0.44333333,
        0.72333333, -0.7       ,  0.79      , -1.51333333, -0.71      ,
        1.64333333, -1.28333333, -0.73333333, -0.3       , -0.29      ])
Coordinates:
  * time     (time) datetime64[ns] 1984-12-01 1985-12-01 ... 2013-12-01
```

Comment: Maybe this helps: https://xskillscore.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/xskillscore.core.resampling.resample_iterations.html#

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out by using reassigning the shuffled samples the same dates as the original series and then the correlations are calulated:

```
# Number of bootstrap samples
num_bootstrap_samples = 1000

# Function to calculate spearman correlation
def calculate_correlation(data1, data2):
    return xs.spearman_r(data1, data2, dim='time')

# Calculate the observed correlation
observed_correlation = calculate_correlation(cru_djf_uv, nino_djf)

# Initialize an array to store bootstrap samples
bootstrap_correlations = np.zeros((num_bootstrap_samples, cru_djf_uv.shape[1], cru_djf_uv.shape[2]))

# Perform bootstrap resampling
for i in range(num_bootstrap_samples):
    # Resample with replacement
    resampled_indices = np.random.choice(cru_djf_uv.shape[0], cru_djf_uv.shape[0], replace=False)
    resampled_cru = cru_djf_uv.isel(time=resampled_indices)
    resampled_cru['time'] = (cru_djf_uv.time)
       
    # Calculate correlation for the resampled data
    bootstrap_correlations[i, :, :] = calculate_correlation(resampled_cru, nino_djf)
```